# How to execute string function in for() sentence?

Tags: javascript

html :

```
<input id="inputAddress_data"/ value="apple">
<ul>
    <li class="adrList_3a">abc</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">def</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">123</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">456</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">ap</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">apple</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">banana</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">bananapple</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">waple</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">abc</li>
    <li class="adrList_3a">abc</li>
    ....... more than 50,000<li>.
</ul>
```

js :

```
inputAddress_data = document.getElementById('inputAddress_data');
adrList_3a = document.getElementsByClassName('adrList_3a');

for(i=0; i<adrList_3a.length; i++) {
    if(adrList_3a[i].match(/inputAddress_data.value/gi)) {
        adrList_3a[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find if the value of lists equals with input.value.
So I wrote this code.
But it didn't work with this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I think means of this error message is that `'match'` is not a defined function.

But I'm sure that `match()` is an existing function. I learned that from w3schools 3 minutes ago.

Comment: As you seem to loop through a pretty large array of elements, you could use this type of loop instead : 

`for(i=0, len=adrList_3a.length; i<len; i++) { /* .... */ }`

This way, the value of `adrList_3a.length` is not re-evaluated at each loop, which could save some time on large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A few errors here:

1. You need to actually check the element's value with the `innerHTML` property
2. You can't compose a regex literal with dynamic values - you need to use the `RegExp` constructor.

This should work:

```
inputAddress_data = document.getElementById('inputAddress_data');
adrList_3a = document.getElementsByClassName('adrList_3a');

for(i=0; i<adrList_3a.length; i++) {
    if(adrList_3a[i].innerHTML.match(new RegExp(inputAddress_data.value,'gi'))) {
        adrList_3a[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: miscapitalized `innerHTML`

Comment: @PaulRoub Oops, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`match()` *is* an existing method - on strings. You're not looking at strings, you're looking at `li` elements. `li` elements don't have a `match()` method.

`li.innerHTML` returns a string, and you can `match()` on that.

But you need to get that `value` into a regular expression; right now you're actually searching for `inputAddress_d...`

So:

```
var re = new RegEx(inputAddress_data.value, "gi");

for(i = 0; i < adrList_3a.length; i++) {
    if(adrList_3a[i].innerHTML.match(re)) {
        adrList_3a[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that adrList_3a[i] ise'nt a string  and dosen't have a match function of corse
you can use textContent in some browsers or inner html

```
inputAddress_data = document.getElementById('inputAddress_data');
adrList_3a = document.getElementsByClassName('adrList_3a');

for(i=0; i<adrList_3a.length; i++) {
if(adrList_3a[i].textContent.match(new RegExp(inputAddress_data.value,"gi"))) {
    adrList_3a[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```